# Bacon.js and awaiting AJAX response

Tags: bacon.js

I've been trying to get something like the following working:

```
var showAjaxIndicator = ajaxRequest.awaiting(ajaxResponse)
```

What I'm seeing however is that `showAjaxIndicator` will finish on `true` -- I do not see a final `false` when the request has finished / ended.

Here's a JSFiddle of what I'm doing: http://jsfiddle.net/umx2sjsj/2/

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is with `Bacon.once` - it works synchronously which is different from normal streams. This is often the problem when you are trying stuff out in jsfiddle.

I forked your fiddle to a new one with `Bacon.later(0, call)` instead of `Bacon.once(call)`, this solves the problem.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wbf8v39k/